# Enable the nnbd experiment in pana and on pub.dev

Tags: flutter, dart, non-nullable

I published a package and get a devastating health result from the pub server with the error message:

> This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.

Actually, that's what I did!

I did enable the nnbd experiment in my `analysis_options.yaml` file and I don't get errors or hints on this topic in my project from dartanalyzer.

How can I make pana running on the pub.dev server process my `analysis_options.yaml`  with nnbd experiment enabled the same way it does locally?